# Comparison of grading systems

Tags: university

What is a good source which compares grading systems in different countries? Which also gives the equivalent of a grade in a country X to that of a country Y?

Comment: This assumes (too) many things. Most importantly, that the grading within countries is internally consistent, or that one grading scheme is more or less just a linear transformation of another.

Answer (score 2):

If your sole purpose of comparing the grades is for International school admission, then I suggest you to look into WES evaluation. Visit the link for WES: http://www.wes.org/students/igpacalc.asp